# How can I find out which authentication protocols a WiFi network uses?

Tags: windows, linux, wireless-networking, authentication, 802.1x

I want to connect my Debian Squeeze machine to my school wireless network with wpa_supplicant.

I think the network uses 802.1X authentication, because when the other students connects to the network for the first time in Windows they enter their username and password then the connection is established. I have asked the the IT staff but they do not known what 802.1X, PEAP EAP etc. is and just say "Enter the login details in the box!".

If I bring a Windows 7 machine to school and successful connects to the network, is it then possible for me to extract the information [and extract a certificate if used on the network] from Windows somehow so i can setup the wpa_supplicant.conf correctly on Debian?

The information I want to extract is which protocols are used, like PEAP,MSCHAP etc.

Comment: Sorry, but you're going to have to find someone in your School's Network Administration that knows what they're talking about to at least give you the general details of how to connect.

Comment: Does your school list instructions for setup online anywhere often the setting to set up Mac OSX show the actual settings

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `sudo iwlist scan wlan0` gives you some usable hints.
Be sure to use `sudo` or `su -c` or you will only get data from an old scan.

Example:

```
Cell 19 - Address: 00:26:24:68:5A:85
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=18/70  Signal level=-92 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"UPC0044352"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000002c5dada19b
                Extra: Last beacon: 3198ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000A55504330303434333532
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A7C181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1606001700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180202F0040000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

Here you can see that this AP uses WPA2 TKIP for authentication.

HTH,

Philipp